# power automate dynamic JSON schema from compose output

Tags: json, schema, power-automate

I have a power automate flow where in I want to dynamically pass the JSON schema in the Parse JSON flow. I will be reading JSON data from random files based on user inputs.

User wants to check for criteria 1, so power automate will "read file content" corresponding to "criteria 1", some file from sharepoint like: /Shared Folder/General/criteria1.json

Likewise, if the user input is criteria 2, then it will read from: /Shared Folder/General/criteria2.json

I want to generalize this flow by also dynamically passing the schema for these use cases. For criteria 1, I pass a schema like:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "Volumes": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "Name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "Cluster": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "Node": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "Svm": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "required": [
                    "Name",
                    "Cluster",
                    "Node",
                    "Svm"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of manually mentioning this schema in the parse JSON schema section, I want it to derive it dynamically, say from a "compose" output.

I tried to mention the schema as part of a "compose" variable but was not able to fetch it in the "Parse JSON schema section"

Comment: Why do you want to take that approach? Parse JSON is now for dynamic processing. It wants the schema so it can provide the dynamic content to you. Maybe you just need to look at using expressions to query the data in the JSON. Or, have conditional step with two parse JSON outputs.

Comment: This is because based on user's request, I need to parse a different json file everytime.  So, I wanted to generalize this flow. Suppose, user opt for "choice1", then I need to parse "choice1.json". Again if user opts for choice2, I need to parse choice2.json. so, I was looking for some way to generalise this instead of writing too many conditional statements.

Comment: Ok, but that is why I asked the question. You either have a condition and parse the two types of json structures individually or you use expressions to get the data and not dynamic content. If there’s a decision that needs to be made then that’s life, it’s not magic.

Comment: I understand that. Actually, I am passing data to power automate from power virtual agent as I am working on a chatbot. So, I was thinking of passing the schema dynamically from the virtual agent itself so that power automate would parse the required file instead of writing any decision logic for it. I wish there was an option to pass in the schema somehow to the parseJSon inputs instead of mentioning it manually

Comment: A good thought but it's somewhat pointless.  The point of the schema is to provide you with dynamic content and the only time you can make proper use of that is at design time.  The ability to handle dynamic schemas exists in connectors but again, you use them at design time and have an expectation that the run time will conform to the schema defined at design time.